# how to I go about getting something like this done in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]i have a gridView List and when i click on one I want it to enlarge to display more information almost like a dialog box over current content.

Something like this in the picture. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't paste the full code, but you might use a Stack as the simplest approach.
The easiest way, without animation, is having the GridView as the first child, and when clicking the Tile, pass the tile info, call setState()... and redraw the stack with whatever overlay u want with the selected content view. 
When you get that in place, you might include [Animated widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation) to work on the transition.

Another options is to use Overlays, go to the bottom of this [Medium article](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-adding-animated-overlays-to-your-app-e0bb049eff39), to understand how it works, it is applied to a menu, but the same concept will work for you. Maybe this is a neater approach.

Another cool option might be the use of [Hero animations](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-hero-widgets-in-flutter-d34f441eb026), but I dont know if you can manage to use within the same BuildContext, depends on how you will build the view.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanx @roipeker I will have a look and revert...